# Nvdia driver causing problems after update

Tags: graphics, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10. Yesterday some packages have been updated, including the NVDIA driver to 280.13. After this update, my machine behaves very weird. My task bar is flickering and sometimes disappearing, screens do not pop up and the machine response time is *very* long or there is no response.

I tried to deinstall the nvdia driver and install the '-current' driver again, but this does not help. I also tried to remove the xconf file, but this also doesn't help. How can I either fix the problem or downgrade to the current -1 version?

Best,
Martijn

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me.
I did a bug report for this issue. Please, mark as it happens to you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/984441

To mark it as it happens also to you, click in the green text "This bug affects you?"

Comment: I did. I got my machine up again by removing the libgl1-mesa related  and the nvidia packages. Not as I would like to have it, but at least it's up again...

Comment: In ubuntu 2D is fine enough for me, not big issues. Try it and tell me if it is fine =)

Comment: Also, I don't recommend you to downgrade or install nvidia drivers at your own. Doing this only give me a lot of problems and zero solutions (in other cases and in this case).